# How to configure Kafka for Clickhouse whithout an error being thrown?

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse, sasl-scram

I have two Kafka clusters, the first — ***`Kafka-A`*** — uses a **"SASL SCRAM-SHA-256"** mechanism to authenticate，the other —  ***`Kafka-B`*** — has no configuration set for it.

To be able to connect to `Kafka-A` in **Clickhouse**, I configured a ***`config.xml`*** file as demonstrated bellow:

###### My `config.xml` configuration:

```
<kafka>
    <security_protocol>sasl_plaintext</security_protocol>
    <sasl_mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-256</sasl_mechanism>
    <sasl_username>xxx</sasl_username>
    <sasl_password>xxx</sasl_password>
    <debug>all</debug>
    <auto_offset_reset>latest</auto_offset_reset>
    <compression_type>snappy</compression_type> 
</kafka>
```

At this point I found that I can't connect to Kafka-B using the Kafka engine table. When I try to an **error** occurs that prints the following message:

> StorageKafka (xxx): [rdk:FAIL]
> [thrd:sasl_plaintext://xxx/bootstrap]:
> sasl_plaintext://xxx/bootstrap: SASL SCRAM-SHA-256
> mechanism handshake failed: Broker: Request not valid in current SASL
> state: broker's supported mechanisms:  (after 3ms in state
> AUTH_HANDSHAKE, 4 identical error(s) suppressed)

It seems when connecting to `Kafka-B`, **Clickhouse** also use the SASL authentication, which leads to the error being thrown, since `Kafka-B` servers are not configured with authentication.

**I would like to know how I can configure it correctly to connect to different Kafka clusters?**

Answer (score 1):

CH allows to define kafka config for each topic

Use topic in the name of an XML section:

```xml
<kafka_mytopic>
    <security_protocol>....
    ....
</kafka_mytopic>
```